# (Python) View a list of parents and children, displaying each in order

Tags: python, parent, children, explorer

This is the list at the moment:

```
my_list = [
    {"name": "AAA", "parent": "none", "children": ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD"], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "BBB", "parent": "AAA", "children": ["EEE"], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "CCC", "parent": "AAA", "children": ["FFF"], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "DDD", "parent": "AAA", "children": [], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "EEE", "parent": "BBB", "children": [], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "FFF", "parent": "CCC", "children": [], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "GGG", "parent": "none", "children": ["HHH"], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "HHH", "parent": "GGG", "children": [], "x": 0, "y": 0},
]
```

What I expect:

```
AAA (0, 0)
    BBB (20, 20)
        EEE (40, 40)
    CCC (20, 60)
        FFF (40, 80)
    DDD (20, 100)
GGG (0, 120)
    HHH (0, 140)
```

I have a list, where its values are dictionaries with the following keys: "name", "parent", "children", "x" and "y". The list is ordered according to how each element was created: first "AAA", then "BBB", and I would like to order it not by its creation, but by each element within its parent.

Also, a second problem would be positioning it at X and Y (for a project I'm creating). Basically, for every parent to the left or above the element, it will be dragged 20px to the right or below. So in this example, the "CCC" element has "AAA" as a parent, so it's 20px to the right, while "AAA", "BBB" and "EEE" are above it. So the position of "CCC" is (20, 60).

I tried something like the one below. I can even read the first line of parents normally, but the children within each child just isn't read or understood the way I want. If anyone can help me I will be forever grateful.

```
for value in name_list:
    if value["parent"] == "none":
        loop = True
        loop_list = value["children"]
        while loop:
            for child_name in loop_list:
                child = get_item(child_name)

                if len(child["children"]) != 0:
                    loop_list = child["children"]

                print("result") ;(
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you want something like this:

```
my_list = [
    {"name": "AAA", "parent": "none", "children": ["BBB", "CCC", "DDD"], "x": 0, "y": 0},
    {"name": "BBB", "parent": "AAA", "children": ["EEE"], "x": 20, "y": 20},
    {"name": "CCC", "parent": "AAA", "children": ["FFF"], "x": 20, "y": 60},
    {"name": "DDD", "parent": "AAA", "children": [], "x": 20, "y": 100},
    {"name": "EEE", "parent": "BBB", "children": [], "x": 40, "y": 40},
    {"name": "FFF", "parent": "CCC", "children": [], "x": 40, "y": 80},
    {"name": "GGG", "parent": "none", "children": ["HHH"], "x": 0, "y": 120},
    {"name": "HHH", "parent": "GGG", "children": [], "x": 0, "y": 140},
]

def print_tree(node, indent=0):
    print("    " * indent + f"{node['name']} ({node['x']}, {node['y']})")
    for child_name in node['children']:
        child = next(item for item in my_list if item["name"] == child_name)
        print_tree(child, indent+1)

# set initial coordinates for the root nodes
for node in my_list:
    if node['parent'] == 'none':
        print_tree(node)
```

Output:

```
AAA (0, 0)
    BBB (20, 20)
        EEE (40, 40)
    CCC (20, 60)
        FFF (40, 80)
    DDD (20, 100)
GGG (0, 120)
    HHH (0, 140)
```